# How to create a slider with dots

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to have a slider bar on the page with 10 dots. "items.slider". I want each item in slider to be a DOT. All the 10 dots are visible all the time with only 1 dot having the focus. The focus changes every 5 secs to the next dot. At the end of the list, focus goes back to the first dot.

I was trying to have a canvas and create 10 small circles in it etc.

How can I do this best?

As asked for:
http://jsfiddle.net/Jh73K/8/

Comment: Why negative vote. I mentioned that I tried a canvas with 10 circles in it. I toggle the color of focused item every 5 secs. I am just looking for information how people have solved this in the past. I am relatively new to HTML/CSS layouts/design

Comment: You were probably downvoted because you gave no code examples or test cases for what you've tried already. Can you provide a quick example on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: The FAQ didn't say one has to post the code of what he tried.

Comment: I tried something like this http://jsfiddle.net/Jh73K/8/. I just dont think this is the right way. Please help me with the right approach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this link [here](http://manicmouse.com/image-free-apple-style-pagination-with-css3/). You can use the same CSS/HTML and then the following javascript to change the active item. Remember the code below is for the HTML mentioned in that link.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    setInterval(function() {
        var o = $("ol.pagination").find(".on").removeClass("on");
        if ($(o).is(':last-child')) $("ol.pagination").find("li:first-child").addClass("on");
        else $(o).next().addClass("on");
    }, 5000);
});
```

​See if this is what you want.
EDIT: By the way, here's a fiddle for the same: http://jsfiddle.net/W8kZf/.

Comment: Just a quick question. This markup uses CSS3. To do it in CSS, I need to use dots images?